# XPage view control search not working

Tags: full-text-search, xpages, lotus-domino

I am new to domino designer and I am required to develop an application with it. I have went through some tutorials and I am stuck at the search function. I have followed guides I found but the search function in view control is not functioning. When I input anything into the search string(even static value), I get a server error 500. The error code is not very useful for solving my problem.(I have the full text index enabled.)

I tried to create my forms and views with the SiteFinderDemo template. I do not get an error but any search string returns 0 results.

I can modify the SiteFinderFinal's codes to work the way I want properly with the demo documents, but the search function else where just cannot work.

I also noticed new documents created with forms or xpages within the SiteFinderDemo instead of the agent do not work with the search function. I assume it has something to do with the full text searching, but I cannot find any information about it. What am I supposed to set up my application so that the search in view control can work without the server error, and what should I do to make new documents work with the search?

Thank you very much and sorry for such a long question.

Comment: You can use the XPages Log File Reader on OpenNTF to see the details of that error 500 you are getting. https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader

Comment: Try this: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=FCF80DF9CD9A74D1852575F600675AB2#mobileViewer

Comment: Thank you very much, I now can do a search using the "keys" instead of the "search" do perform the search function. However I want to do a search with multiple keys. I knew I could use "and" to connect the strings in "search" when I tried it in the SiteFinderDemo, I do not know how to implement this on the "keys". It says that I need to use an array, but I cannot find further information about the implementation. How should I implement my arrays of strings as the keys? Thank you.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem now, I finally know how to update the full text search. Thanks a lot!!